# Neo4j Spark connector error: import.org.neo4j.spark._ object neo4j is not found in package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I have my scala code running in spark connecting to Neo4j on my mac.  I wanted to test it on my windows machine but cannot seem to get it to run, I keep getting the error:

```
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.43.4:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1508360735468).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Loading neo4jspark.scala...
<console>:23: error: object neo4j is not a member of package org
       import org.neo4j.spark._
              ^
```

Which gives subsequent errors of:

```
changeScoreList: java.util.List[Double] = []
<console>:87: error: not found: value neo
                         val initialDf2 = neo.cypher(noBbox).partitions(5).batch(10000).loadDataFrame
                                          ^
<console>:120: error: not found: value neo
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I am executing it like this:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=TestNeo4j --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jspark.scala
```

Says it finds all the dependencies yet the code throws the error when using neo.  Not sure what else to try?  Not sure why this doesn't work on my windows box and does my mac.  Spark version 2.2 the same, neo4j up and running same versions, scala too, even java (save for a few minor revisions version differences)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21339) (with a related one [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18648)), the [fix](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18708) for which is part of the Spark 2.2.1 release.

Comment: ahh okay (I had this working before on windows), so I guess I need to add these jars to the class path as a work around?

Comment: I did get the latest version and tried it, but I still got the errors.  Do I need to find these jars manually and move them to the classpath my windows has?

Comment: @Codejoy: Spark 2.2.1 hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Misread :) got the 2.1.1 ha. Guess I am waiting for the 2.2.1 release